# File writing issue while using async

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have a function like below to write files into logfile :

```
private async Task<string> GetResponseString(string test)
{        
    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://something/api/apimethod"....);        
    ProcessWrite("C:\\"log.txt","some text to write").Wait();        
}

static Task ProcessWrite(string filePath,string text)
{
    return WriteTextAsync(filepath,text);
}

static async Task WriteTextAsync(string filePath,string text)
{
    byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
            FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite,
            bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
    {

            await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
    };

}
```

It's used to write the file, when I run in Visual Studio, I am able to write the file, but when I deploy it in IIS web server. Then writing contents to file stop working. But there are no exceptions.

How can I make logs to write when I deploy it is?

Comment: Just a question; why not use `await ProcessWrite`? With a `static async Task ProcessWrite`? With an `return await WriteTextAsync(filepath,text);`?... I might as well post this as answer ;-)

Comment: Try changing code to return await WriteTextAsync(filepath,text); of the ProcessWrite function

Comment: @Stefan Marking `ProcessWrite` as async is not nessesary. Just awaiting it. It may even be better because it doesn't force a context switch which it would do in certain environments.

Comment: @NtFreX: good point.

Comment: i did it without async, still i have the same issue.. but it words perfectly in visual studio, only the issue is when we deploy in IIS

Comment: Strange thing is that there's no exception. Any how, have you checked the IIS user's access rights?

Comment: i dont have access rights to IIS ... is that a issue?

Comment: yes that's the issue, the IIS default user doesn't have the permission to create the file "C:\\"log.txt"

Comment: @SmartestVEGA how do you know there are no exceptions? What code calls `GetResponseString`? Did you debug the code? Check the logs? How, when you say you have no access rights to IIS? If that method gets called by a Web API action you *would* get a 500, no matter what, unless something *hides* or *ignores* exceptions, eg a `catch{}` block

Comment: @SmartestVEGA as for logging in general, *don't* write your own. Use a library like NLog, Serilog or log4net and configure it to write to a folder accessible by the application pool account. If that location is *outside* the site's folder you'll have to explicitly add permissions to that folder.

Comment: How do you intend to handle the case when to threads (requests) needs to write to the log at the same time?

Comment: are we sure this is a IIS access issue, because i need to raise ticket and need multiple approvals .. also i commented ProcessWrite still i have the issue

Comment: i dont need logs..i just write a text file in file system to see code execution reached there, but it is not reaching after the async call